X-val Relative Error increases as trees get more complex
I'm building a CART model using rpart. Here is the code that I used:
train_rpart <- rpart(
  y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4,
  data = train, 
  method = "class", 
  control = rpart.control(
    minsplit = 20,    
    minbucket = 5, 
    cp = 0, 
    maxdepth = 5, 
    xval = 10
  ),
  parms = list(
    split = "gini", 
    loss = matrix(c(0, 1, 10, 0), 
    byrow = TRUE, 
    nrow = 2
  )
)

plotcp(train_rpart)

Here is the result that I got:

I know that the reason why the x-val relative error got larger as the size of tree increases is due to overfitting. However, I'm unsure what I can do to fix this besides what I've already done. I have tried SMOTE to balance the dataset but it still doesn't help. I would appreciate any help and suggestions. Thank you!
